# What is the difference between calling "ret" vs calling the sys_exit number assembly gcc

Tags: assembly

In gcc assembly, the main function can either return or exit, where both work. Here I have two programs, where one exits with a syscall `int $0x80`, and the other simply calls ret. What is the difference?

```
.data
hello: .string "Hello, World!"
.globl main
main:
  push %rbx
  movq $hello, %rdi
  call puts
  pop %rbx

  ret
```

and

```
.data
hello: .string "Hello, World!"
.globl main
main:
  push %rbx
  movq $hello, %rdi
  call puts
  pop %rbx

  movq $1, %rax
  movq $0, %rbx
  int $0x80
```

I am aware that ret pops the instruction pointer off the stack, but what does that really do in this case?

Comment: If you link with the _C_ runtime, it will do the `call main`. When you do a `ret` it returns to the _C_ runtime which eventually kills the process. The sys_exit syscall avoids returning back to the _C_ runtime that called main and requests the OS to stop the process.

Comment: @MichaelPetch what if I don't link with c runtime(assuming I change my puts function, of course)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Additionally, what are the differences between both options

Comment: If you don't link with the runtime, and you are on linux, you simply can't use `ret` because there is nowhere to return to.

Comment: @Jester Cool, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that calls `main` looks like this:

```
int status = main(argc, argv, envp);
exit(status);
```

if `main` returns, `exit(status)` is executed.  `exit` is a C library function which flushes all stdio streams, invokes `atexit()` handlers and finally calls `_exit(status)`, which is the C wrapper for the `SYS_exit` system call.  If you use the C runtime (e.g. by having your program start at `main` or by using any libc functions), I strongly recommend you to never call `SYS_exit` directly so the C runtime has a chance to correctly deinitialize the program.  The best idea is usually to call `exit()` or to return from `main` unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: This response looks like it was meant for a c question... my question is about assembly. Either way, the comments answer my question much better than this answer, sorry.

Comment: @Riolku that C maps directly to asm on any platform.  C is a common way of describing what asm does, as a short-hand.  You can single-step into the actual asm that called your `main` by using GDB's `stepi` command to step past the `ret` at the end of `main`.  In glibc for x86-64, the asm looks something like `call rax` / `mov edi, eax` / `call exit`, IIRC, and lives in libc itself.  The CRT startup code passes it a function pointer to `main`.