# The x86 assembly code run successfully but vscode show error without more information

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-frame

I am new to assmbly, and I have some problem. I compiled the following code with GCC:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.section .data
number:
    .int 65

message:
    .ascii "The number is %d %d.\n\0"

.section .text
    .globl  _main

_main:
    push ebp

    lea eax, [message]
    mov ebx, number
    mov [esp + 8], ebx
    add ebx, 1
    mov [esp + 4], ebx
    mov [esp], eax

    call _printf

    pop ebp
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

It can display the message `The number is 66 65.` on the console, but the vscode show some errors without more information.

[vscode output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFCr3.png)

I tried to remove the line `mov [esp + 4], ebx`, and the error that vscode showed fixed.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.section .data
number:
    .int 65

message:
    .ascii "The number is %d %d.\n\0"

.section .text
    .globl  _main

_main:
    push ebp

    lea eax, [message]
    mov ebx, number
    mov [esp + 8], ebx
    add ebx, 1
    mov [esp], eax

    call _printf

    pop ebp
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

[vscode output after fixing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRzS1.png)

Can anyone help me to solve the problem and explan it? Thank you!

Comment: The red vscode symbol indicates a nonzero exit code from the program. Blue indicates an exit code of 0. It's not clear to me why your code exits 0 in one case but not the other. The return value of _main (which is also used as the exit code by gcc) is in eax, which is cleared in both cases. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51353096/2708313

Comment: Your function overwrites its return address and then tries to `ret`, so it'll crash.  Look at where `ESP` is pointing when `mov [esp+4], ebx` runs, because you're using `mov` instead of `push` and didn't reserve any stack space first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Mr./Ms. Peter's answer (and also thanks for Mr./Ms.
rpatel3001's answer), I solve this problem by reserving the stack space.

Here is the code after modified:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.section .data
number:
    .int 65

message:
    .ascii "The number is %d %d.\n\0"

.section .text
    .globl  _main

_main:
    push ebp
    sub esp, 8 # <-----

    lea eax, [message]
    mov ebx, number
    mov [esp + 8], ebx
    add ebx, 1
    mov [esp + 4], ebx
    mov [esp], eax

    call _printf

    add esp, 8 # <-----

    pop ebp
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```